# RxJS Observable & Observer issues

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

I have an Angular 2 service that executes a few steps to authenticate and log in an app user. Any time I try to call next() on my Observer I get an error that it is undefined. The only place I can successfully call next() on it is inside contructor when the Observable is instantiated.

If I call authenticateUser() I get an error that this.isLoggedIn is undefined.

**AuthService.ts**

```
public isLoggedIn$: Observable<boolean>;
private isLoggedIn: Observer<boolean>;

constructor(...) {

    this.isLoggedIn$ = new Observable<boolean>(
        (observer: Observer<boolean>) => {
            this.isLoggedIn = observer;

            // this works fine
            this.doLogin();

        }).share()

}

private doLogin = ():void => {

    let context:AuthContextModel = this.authContextService.getAuthContext();

    if (context) {

        let isAuthenticated = this.isAuthenticated(context);

        if (isAuthenticated) {

            this.doCreateCurrentUserContext(context)
                .then((result) => {return this.doNotifyLoggedInStatus(result);});
        }
    }
};


private doNotifyLoggedInStatus = (result:boolean):Promise<boolean> => {

    this.isLoggedIn.next(result);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        return resolve(true);
    });
};


public authenticateUser = (user: string, pass: string):Promise<boolean> => {
    return this.doFetchToken(user, pass)
        .then((fetchTokenData) => {return this.doStoreToken(fetchTokenData);})
        .then((authContext) => {return this.doCreateCurrentUserContext(authContext);})
        .then((result) => {return this.doNotifyLoggedInStatus(result);});

};
```

Comment: I guess that's because `isLoggedIn$` wasn't subscribed.

Comment: @estus thanks.. that was it! I have been banging my head for a couple hours now.. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to call `.next()` on an Observer outside of the instantiation of the Observable, you should use a Subject rather than separate Observables and Observers. Subjects act as both. You can subscribe to them separately from where you pass events to it.

There are different kinds of Subjects, but for your situation, I would recommended a BehaviorSubject. Whenever you subscribe to it, not only will it catch future events, it will return the *last* event fired before the subscription happened. This is useful for an authentication component because you won't have to write separate code for a successful log in and actually checking if a user is authenticated after it has already happened (or a later sign out). It's really simple too.

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/Rx'; 

//...
  public isLoggedIn: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = BehaviorSubject.create();

  constructor(...) { }

  private doLogin():void {

    //... Do the log in
    this.isLoggedIn.next(true);

  };
```

All you need to do wherever you want to check for log in status is grab the BehaviorSubject and subscribe to it. It doesn't matter whether or not the subscription happens before or after doLogin() was called.

If you intend to preserve the login state on refresh, all you'd need to do in the constructor is check for authentication and call the `.next(true)` on the BehaviorSubject as usual.

See also:

[ReactiveX Subject docs](http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html)

[Intro to Rx BehaviorSubjects](http://www.introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/02_KeyTypes.html#BehaviorSubject)

Comment: Thanks, this was a tremendous help. One more question.. whats the trick to getting the observed value to influence the DOM? *ngIf="isLoggedIn"

Comment: `*ngIf="isLoggedIn | async"` *should* work. The async pipe is necessary because it unwraps the values from the Observable (of the BehaviorSubject). Otherwise, you're just giving it a Subject without specifying what to do with it. Angular won't like that. If you want to use it to affect the DOM outside of your log in component, you'll have to retrieve the isLoggedIn BehaviorSubject so it really should be located in some sort of authentication service. If that doesn't work, just subscribe to it manually on your component, assign the values to a boolean property and bind *ngIf to that.

Comment: I have a CurrentUser component that just displays "Logged in As foo123" in the header of my layout. This only updates when I refresh the app after logging in. My CurrentUser component gets the AuthService injected and I have subscribed to the isLoggedIn behavior subject in the constructor. I also have a LoginComponent that gets the AuthService injected and the login form calls the AuthService.authenticateUser() which if all goes will calls next(true) on the behavior subject. But this impl only worked when I reload the app after logging in

Comment: Can you put the CurrentUser component, its parent, the LoginComponent,  their templates, and the AuthService in a plunker or fiddle and send it to me? It doesn't need to compile or work, I just need to look at the code.

Comment: I will post it up this evening... but how do I debug this stuff? I think my CurrentUser constructor (where I subscribe to the AuthService.isloggedIn) is running before my auth service constructor which is where the Observable is instantiated.

Comment: CurrentUser component is injected at the App.Component directives array

Comment: Put a console.log("whatever") next to where you call `isLoggedIn.next(true)` for authenticateUser() to make sure it's being called when you log in. If that works as it should, try another console.log in the subscription for the CurrentUser component and see if that runs when you log in. If that doesn't run, put another in the CurrentUser constructor outside of the subscription and make sure that runs when the page loads when you AREN'T logged in. Generally, what I do to debug these types of problems is put console.logs everywhere and see what runs and what doesn't.

Comment: Also, on my original answer I made a mistake for the BehaviorSubject creation. Make sure it looks like this: `public isLoggedIn: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = BehaviorSubject.create();`

Comment: I figured it out.. I had a rouge providers: [AuthService] in my login component. This was creating a new AuthService instance and clobbering the first one that had the subscriptions wired up. Thanks a million for your help. This code is going to assist in flying a satellite soon and you helped write it... LOL

Comment: Great! Glad you got it worked out! A satellite?!?! No way!! Can you send me any more information about it or is it like a top secret spy satellite?

Comment: Haha, that's so awesome!